# Интеграция R с C# и WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, r, интеграция

Не очень хорошо знаком с языком программирования R. Можно ли сделать систему подобного плана?

Допустим, есть модуль написанный на R. Для него по ходу дела должен формироваться набор входных данных. При чем, эти данные формируются посредством C#. Далее вызывается этот модуль R, который формирует отчет, например, какие-то данные. Эти данные отображаются на гуи WPF, то есть WPF отображает R markup или какие-то графики R внутри какого-то своего контрола. Так можно?

Второй вопрос, заодно. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы входные данные R динамично обновлялись с помощью C#, соответственно, чтобы графики на WPF интерфейсе динамично обновлялись?

Благодарю.

---

**ПС:** попробую начать конкурс. В идеале, буду рад краткому или развернутому описанию решения, а не только объяснению почему да или почему нет.

**Upd:** Собственный ответ про shiny я добавил намного позже, так что чисто по upvote-ам судить не объективно. А можно даже взглянуть на мой ответ.

Comment: Для `C++` есть http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html. Есть вариант интеграции с `RServe`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455783/2772330

Comment: Можете еще посмотреть в сторону https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/, хоть и F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В итоге приемлемое для меня решение оказалось следующим:**

*Acceptable solution*: [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/)

---

Прошу прощения, опишу решение только вкратце (*shortly*):

**1)** *[R Portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/)*

**2)** Программа *runapp*:

```
.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "C:\\Users\\Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zzzz\\xxxx\\Server\\Reports\\pckgs") )

.libPaths()

if(!require(shiny)){
    install.packages("shiny", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", destdir="C:\\Users\\Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zzzz\\xxxx\\Server\\Reports\\pckgs")
    library(shiny)
}

if(!require(parallel)){
    install.packages("parallel", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", destdir="C:\\Users\\Andrey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zzzz\\xxxx\\Server\\Reports\\pckgs")
    library(parallel)
}

options(echo=TRUE) # if you want see commands in output file
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
print(args)

folder_address <- args[1]
port <- as.numeric(args[2])

x <- system("ipconfig", intern=TRUE)
z <- x[grep("IPv4", x)]
ip <- gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", z) 
# print(paste0("the Shiny Web application runs on: http://", ip, ":1234"))

runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=FALSE, port = port, host = ip)
```

**3)** Чтобы понять концепцию, достаточно батника *`thebatnik.bat`* :

```
C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\RPlay\Shiny\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\RScript.exe "C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Temp\zzzz\xxxx\Server\Reports\runapp.r" "C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Temp\zzzz\xxxx\Server\Reports\rep1"  1234 
PAUSE
```

Здесь 1234 - номер порта (*port number*)

**before 4)**

```
library(shiny)
```

**4)** Первая составляющая отчета - серверная. (*Server part*)

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {

# Histogram of the Old Faithful Geyser Data ----
# with requested number of bins
# This expression that generates a histogram is wrapped in a call
# to renderPlot to indicate that:
#
# 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
#    re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
# 2. Its output type is a plot
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

x    <- faithful$waiting
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
     xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
     main = "Histogram of waiting times")

})

}
```

**5)** UI по части R+Shiny (*UI part*):

```
# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("Dynaic report example"),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
  sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
              label = "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30)

),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(

  # Output: Histogram ----
  plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

)
```

)
  )

**after 5)**

```
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Пункты 4-5 можно либо в одном либо в нескольких файлах в папке rep1.

(*4-5 are the files in rep1 folder*)

**6)** в данном примере хостится на

```
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.128
```

, а чтобы сделать чтобы несколько отчетов на одном порте, то может понадобится (если не ошибаюсь) (*if i'm right, you can use the following tool to run multiple reports on one port*):

[nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/)

**7)** На этом этапе готов отчет, который после запуска батника можно открыть из браузера (*in browser*):

[image: Если в браузере, то получается так]

**8)** Но ведь есть wpf-ный конторол (кстати и winform-овский тоже есть) (*wpf control*):

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://192.168.2.128:1234"></WebBrowser>
```

*[Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)*

```
//winforms - на самостоятельную работу, homework
```

Так же есть:

```
Process.Start("thebatnik.bat");
```

**9)** Данные можно считывать из базы данных средствами R. Так же R умеет воспринимать данные в других форматах, например из файлов или, возможно, других источников. Например, файлы с данными могут приготавливаться средствами c#. Об обновлении источника данных - это интересный вопрос, но до этого у меня не дошло, остановился на самой начальной стадии, на proof-of-concept-е. Думаю, что вопрос обновления источника данных - решаемый. Но пока всё, потому что о тонкостях данной схемы, к сожалению, мне сейчас мне думать не актуально. (*sorry, can not say about updating source, but, probably, it is possible; files with data can be prepared by means of c#; or other solutions to read data like R tools to work with database*)

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю воспользоваться идеями, изложенными [здесь](https://coders-corner.net/2015/11/01/use-r-in-c/), а именно:

- Установить R.NET
- Использовать R в коде на C# при помощи evaluate, например, так, как указано по ссылке выше:

  ```
  using System;
  using RDotNet;

  namespace RCalculator
  {
      class Program
      {
      static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              string result;
              string input;
              REngine engine;

              //запустить R engine            
              REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
              engine = REngine.GetInstance();
              engine.Initialize();

              //ввод
              Console.WriteLine("Введите выражение");
              input = Console.ReadLine();

              //вычисление
              CharacterVector vector = engine.Evaluate(input).AsCharacter();
              result = vector[0];

              //закрыть R
              engine.Dispose();

              //вывод
              Console.WriteLine("");
              Console.WriteLine("Result: '{0}'", result);
              Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу...");
              Console.ReadKey();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Вывод вы получаете в C#, то есть, вы не ограничены по средствам его дальнейшей доставки. Таким образом, к WPF Вам нужно будет обращаться так, как Вы это делаете обычно в C#.

Comment: Спасибо! Ну, [слышал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562977/2772330), что R.Net имеет много ошибок и не поддерживается более. Во вторых, у самого R более продвинутые возможности визуализации, например, графики (R markup). Но, спасибо за ответ...

Comment: Ну да, еще, какое-то более основательное решение интересует, например с 50 большими таблицами входных данных и, например, 30-ю различными модулями R. Правда, не знаю, как достаточно объяснить эту мысль.

Comment: Больше интересует RServe, чем R.Net

Comment: Благодарю Вас за участие. Система сама назначила вам 75 вместо 150, думаю, это справедливо. Короче, понял, что мой вопрос это не ко стэк оверфлову, а (своего свободного времени нет) ко фрилансерам.